# What's wrong with Metal instrument simdgroup_load or simdgroup_store?

Tags: ios, macos, gpu, simd, metal

OS: MacOS 12.2.1

Hardwear: MacBook Pro 2020, M1

Metal: 2.4

Xcode： 13.2.1

Here is my test computer kernel,which **read input buffer with simdgroup_load adn write output buffer with simdgroup_store**

```
kernel void fun(
const device half * Src                 [[ buffer(0) ]],
constant uint4 & SrcShape               [[ buffer(1) ]],
device half * Dst                       [[ buffer(2) ]],
constant uint4 & DstShape               [[ buffer(3) ]],
const device half * Weight              [[ buffer(4) ]],
ushort3 threadgroup_position_in_grid    [[ threadgroup_position_in_grid ]],
ushort3 thread_position_in_threadgroup  [[ thread_position_in_threadgroup ]],
ushort3 threads_per_threadgroup         [[ threads_per_threadgroup ]],
ushort3 thread_position_in_grid         [[ thread_position_in_grid ]])
{

    const int SrcSlices = (int)SrcShape[0];
    const int SrcHeight = (int)SrcShape[1];
    const int SrcWidth  = (int)SrcShape[2];
    const int DstSlices = (int)DstShape[0];
    const int DstHeight = (int)DstShape[1];
    const int DstWidth  = (int)DstShape[2];
    const int Kernel_X = 3;
    const int KernelElemNum = 3 * 3;
    const int N_Pack = 8;

   // Test only 1 thread
   if(thread_position_in_grid.z != 0|| thread_position_in_grid.y != 0|| thread_position_in_grid.x * N_Pack != 0) return;

    simdgroup_half8x8 sgMatY;
    simdgroup_load(sgMatY, Src);

    simdgroup_store(sgMatY, Dst);

}
```

It's a simple shader, **however output buffer only save first 2 values from input buffer，the other 62 values are ALL ZERO.**

Here is the result from Xcode Metal Capture

[image][image]

How to debug or fix it？

Answer (score 0):

Bug fixed.
Anyone who intent to use this feature can refer in the implementation in TF-Lite:

https://github.com/alpa-projects/tensorflow-alpa/blob/ee8f6612b515ada4509fa53491c5ba5b3ef8524a/tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/common/tasks/conv_metal_simd.cc